# How do I fix the Grosta bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I went to Heartwood Mill and talked to Grosta about her husband's (Leifnarr's) murder, there was no option to tell her about his death. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the following as recommended by the [elderscroll.wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Grosta)

> > Please reload an old save to confirm if the bug is still happening.
> >         If the bug is still occurring, please post the bug report with the appropriate system template  360  / XB1  ,  PS3  / PS4  ,  PC  / MAC 
> >     , depending on which platform(s) the bug has been encountered on.
> >         Be descriptive when listing the bug and fixes, but avoid having conversations in the description and/or using first-person-anecdotes:
> >     such discussions belong on the appropriate forum board.
> >
> > PC   This is a commonly broken objective and Grosta's state
> >     seems to be bugged. Current details are not known about the true quest flow for the object, but Leifnarr's corpse can be found in a
> >     secret room at Broken Helm Hollow. The corpse is an unnamed Nord and
> >     will give the one the objective to report Leiffnar's death to his
> >     family. Talking to either Grosta or Gralnach about finding him is not
> >     an option.
> >             Activating the quest before anything else usually prevents this bug.
>
> PC(Fix)   Enter CompleteAllObjectives 000E3EA5 into the console command. This forces the quest to be completed.
>
> PC(Fix)   Enter SetStage E3EA5 30 into the console command for Grosta. This will set her to correct state and allow notification
>   of his death.